# Async Functions of Entity Framework not running properly

Tags: c#, entity-framework

As I know, asynchronous functions return immediately. The sample code below confirms me.

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    StartTasks2();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void StartTasks2() 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Task2 Started: {DateTime.Now:s.ffff}");
    AddPersonFake();
    Console.WriteLine($"Task2 Finished: {DateTime.Now:s.ffff}");
}

private static async void AddPersonFake() 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"AddPersonFake Started: {DateTime.Now:s.ffff}");
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine($"AddPersonFake Finished: {DateTime.Now:s.ffff}");
}
```

[image]

But this code is not working (I'm waiting for the result as above):

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    StartTasks1();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void StartTasks1() 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Task1 Started: {DateTime.Now:s.ffff}");
    AddPerson();
    Console.WriteLine($"Task1 Finished: {DateTime.Now:s.ffff}");
}

private static async void AddPerson() 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"AddPerson Started: {DateTime.Now:s.ffff}");

    using ( TempDbContext context = new TempDbContext() ) 
    {
        context.Persons.Add(new Person());
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"AddPerson Finished: {DateTime.Now:s.ffff}");
}
```

[image]

How can I return immediately from `AddPerson()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I learned here on StackOverflow yestarday, you can do it using:

```
private static async void AddPerson() {
    await Task.Yield();
    Console.WriteLine($"AddPerson Started: {DateTime.Now:s.ffff}");
    using ( TempDbContext context = new TempDbContext() ) {
        context.Persons.Add(new Person());
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"AddPerson Finished: {DateTime.Now:s.ffff}");
}
```

`Task.Yield()` will start incompeleted Task and when awaiting it, that is the place where your asynchronous code will start.

In your original code, method `AddPerson` is running `synchronously` until it reaches the first `await`